# Jquery cross fade height jump issue

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, fadeout

I am completely new to jquery and trying to solve height jump during the cross fading two div. Also facing the issue to keep remember action on refreshing the page.

This is my code I am trying to use for cross fade

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#playlist").css("display","none");
    $("#vplaycheck").click(function(){

        if ($("#vplaycheck").is(":checked"))
        {
            $("#playlist").fadeIn("fast");
            $("#v_single").fadeOut("fast");
        }
        else
        {
            $("#playlist").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#v_single").fadeIn("fast");
        }
    });
    if ($("#vplaycheck").is(":checked"))
    {
        $("#playlist").fadeIn("fast");
        $("#v_single").fadeOut("fast");
    }
    else
    {
        $("#playlist").fadeOut("fast");
        $("#v_single").fadeIn("fast");
    }
});


<div>
    <form>      
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="vplaycheck" />Checkbox</label>

        <div id="v_single">
            <h1>Single V</h1>
        </div>

        <div id="playlist">
            <label form="name">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" />

            <label form="info">Comment:</label>
            <input type="textarea" id="info" />
        </div>  
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fadeout I used only fadein and it stops jumping.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the two divs occupy the same space without influencing each other. You can acheive this by positioning them absolutely.

```
form{ position: relative; }  
​#playlist,#v_single{
   position: absolute;
   float: left;            
}
```

Comment: Actually I am trying to add this in Wordpress admin panel and somehow its positioning completely top of the page when i am using absolute or fixed.